# Is there a way to create a filtered list of lists from a list of lists by filtering the 2nd value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists

```
[['darwin','100'],['tesla','-100'],['franklin','200']]
```

I would like to make a new list of lists that filters and outputs out only the lists whose second value is greater than 0

The output should be

```
[['darwin','100'],['franklin','200']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions:

```
>>> my_list = [['darwin', '100'], ['tesla', '-100'], ['franklin', '200']]
>>> [sub_list for sub_list in my_list if int(sub_list[1]) > 0]
[['darwin', '100'], ['franklin', '200']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [['darwin', '100'], ['tesla', '-100'], ['franklin', '200']]

list(filter(lambda x: int(x[1]) > 0, my_list))
```